# General form for ${\large\int} \ \frac{\sin(a x) \cos(b x)}{\frac{1}{f(x)} \ + \ c} dx \ $ known ${\large\int} \sin(a x) \cos(b x) f(x) \ dx$

Tags: calculus

If

$g(x) = {\large\int} \ \sin(a x) \cos(b x) f(x) \ dx$

is known, is there a general form for

${\large\int} \ \frac{\sin(a x) \cos(b x)}{\frac{1}{f(x)} \ + \ c} dx$

that may contain $g(x)$ and possibly $g'(x)$?

I have a hunch that the antiderivative of $sin(x)/(e^{-x}+a)$,

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sin%28x%29%2F%28e%5E%28-x%29%2Ba%29

may be close to the answer.

I have seen hugely difficult problems solved on this site, why not this (albeit very general)?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \sin(x)\cos(x) f(x) dx$ is a number, not a function

Comment: I believe that your question is too difficult to deal with.

Comment: I really don't see the added value having both sine and cosine in your integral, knowing that $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin x \cos x$.